# probability of cards exercise of a probability path

Tags: probability-theory

hello i am solving the exercises in the book a probability path this is in chapter 2 is exercise 23 
But my teacher told me that I must follow the guidelines of that chapter. Does anyone know how to solve it at the level of an advanced probability course?

In the game of bridge 52 distinguishable cards constituting 4 equal suits are distributed at random among 4 players. What is the probability that at least one player has a complete suit?

Currently I have worked in the sample space as we are interested in that when it is dealt we have that the 13 cards can be dealt in this way
$\Omega=w:\left\lbrace w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_{13}\right\rbrace$

$|\Omega|= {52 \choose 13}$
I'm missing the sigma algebra generated by event A which is to get all of the same suit
and the probability to finish the construction

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: thanks how can i delete it to write again later when i try again

Comment: There should be a delete button under the question text.

Comment: I already added what I needed

Comment: You seem to be considering only the probability that one specific player gets dealt a full suit, but the problem asks for the probability that at least one of the four does.  There are $\binom{52}{13,13,13,13}$ possible deals.

Comment: combination with repetition, means that no matter the order they are delivered or obtained

Comment: but the sigma algebra which is?

Comment: It would be the power set of the set of all possible deals.  What is the difficulty?